# Do I need to use an MVC framework for A Professional Static Site

Tags: php, web-deployment-project

I use php for my Static Web Sites, But Do I need to use an MVC framework for A Professional Static Site, What will be the advantages and disadvantages of using one for A Static Site? What are the frameworks that are more suitable for Static Web Sites? So far I did not use any framework for my Static Website Creations, But I thought if it is good to implement a framework to professionalize my work.

Comment: You do not need to use a framework for a static site.  You use a framework if you want to use a framework.

Comment: you can use codeigniter or zend framework for MVC needs. Normally static web site no need to have frame works or MVC. MVC help to handle the modules independently. The site need to be developed by multiple developers or going with continues upgrades will work nicely with MVC.

Comment: What is a "professional" static site and how does it differ from a "non-professional" static site?

Comment: @deceze The word says it all, When I do creation of web sites for commercial purposes, for companies, it is professional, and when I do it for practicing web site development it is non-professional

Comment: There is no *technical* reason to make that distinction at all. If MVC is a well suited solution to developing a site, it makes no difference for whom you're creating that site. You either use MVC because it helps, or you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use MVC framework for static site, because I think you are not going to make any changes in your static website after deploying on server.

But if you have a Professional Static Site, I suggest to use a good framework which is best suitable for you.

Every PHP MVC framework have their own advantages and disadvantages, so only think about advantages of framework. And how that framework is capable of completing and full-filling your requirement.

For your Professional Static Site, I suggest to use Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, etc frameworks which are best suitable for you.

Good luck.